# Why is Automator breaking link between actions?

Tags: macos, automator

I have an Automator workflow which uses a variable to move Finder items to the trash.  It used to work fine, but after editing the workflow, the link between the last two actions is broken.

EDIT: Actually, the workflow seems to be working properly when I run it.  Apparently this problem is only with the UI not displaying correctly.

[image]

Comment: Could it indeed be the `Ignore this action's input` checkbox, which is preventing the input from being of any use to that step?

Comment: That's what it seems like, but as shown in the screenshot, the Options button is greyed out, so I can't see that checkbox.

Comment: That's strange because you should just be able to uncheck it, I am referring to the `Ignot this action's input` checkbox in the `Get Value of Variable` step, not the last step. Uncheck it and run it.

Comment: Thanks, @ProGrammer! I was trying to figure out how to do what he was trying to figure out how *not* to do!